# Can you set a capture filter on journald?

Tags: systemd-journald, journalctl

I have a service that runs in the background. It's controlled by systemd. Any output is captured by journald.

Most of the time, it has very little output. Sometimes though, it runs into a particular condition, and outputs several million warning lines, flooding journald. I've actually had journald crash a few times with a core dump.

These warnings are NOT a bug. They are safe to ignore however.

My question is this: can I tell journald, when it's capturing output from this process, to not capture log entries matching a pattern?

Note: This is different than filtering journald output with grep, or similar. I don't need a display filter. I need a capture filter.

I don't have access to the source code of the program generating the output, so I can't easily make it stop.

Is a bash script wrapper around the program that captures stderr, filters it, and re-transmits filtered messages to stderr the only option?

Comment: Would setting a strict(er) global journald rate-limit help here? There are `RateLimitInterval` and `RateLimitBurst` settings in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

Comment: @Yuri interesting. I didn't know it had a setting that can control this. This would help, but is still not ideal, as other, more important messages by the same process can be ignored if the rate limit is hit. Since in my case, I know which log entries are NOT important, and can write some sort of pattern (string? regex?) to define those, the ideal solution would ignore those messages while letting all others get recorded

Comment: Seeing issues like https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6432, I'm afraid the journald itself doesn't have the ability to filter the inbound traffic.

Comment: Fix the service! Outputting several million lines of messages that will be ignored is Poor Programming Practice. Stop doing that.

Comment: @waltinator You are making the assumption that I'm the one that wrote the service, or that it's somehow broken. It's not. It works exactly as intended, and notifies users when there's a problem. In this case, a missing file. It just so happens that in my case, there are a few million missing files. I'm not going to go into details of why they are missing, but this isn't a problem. I'm not going to learn a new programming language, learn someone else's code, and change the program just so my special case gets treated differently. I can write a wrapper script in minutes if I need to.